# How to calculate compound interest with varying interest rates in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to calculate the compounded interest by product where the interest rate can vary by year.

Simplified table below. `initial_value` is value of the product at start of year 1, `final_value` is the value including interest at end of the respective year.

```
product year    initial_value   interest    final_value
a         1       10000           0.03        10,300.00
a         2                       0.02        10,506.00
a         3                       0.01        10,611.06
b         1       15000           0.04        15,600.00
b         2                       0.06        16,536.00
b         3                       0.07        17,693.52
```

To recreate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (year INTEGER, product CHARACTER,
                   initial_value DECIMAL(10,2), interest DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1, 'a', 10000, 0.03);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (2, 'a', 0, 0.02);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (3, 'a', 0, 0.01);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1, 'b', 15000, 0.04);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (2, 'b', 0, 0.06);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (3, 'b', 0, 0.07);
```

taking product = a for example the number in year 3 should be calculated as `10000 * (1+0.03) * (1+0.02) * (1+0.01)`

The years and number of products can vary so I want to avoid transposing the data by year, but unfortunately can't think of another way to multiply across the rows to get to the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`RECURSIVE CTE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT year, product, initial_value, interest, initial_value*(1+ interest) AS s
  FROM temp
  WHERE initial_value <> 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.year, t.product, t.initial_value, t.interest, s * (1+t.interest)
  FROM temp t
  JOIN cte c
    ON t.product = c.product
    AND t.year = c.year+1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY product, year;
```

Output:

```
┌──────┬─────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ year │ product │ initial_value │ interest │ final_value │
├──────┼─────────┼───────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│    1 │ a       │         10000 │     0.03 │       10300 │
│    2 │ a       │             0 │     0.02 │       10506 │
│    3 │ a       │             0 │     0.01 │    10611.06 │
│    1 │ b       │         15000 │     0.04 │       15600 │
│    2 │ b       │             0 │     0.06 │       16536 │
│    3 │ b       │             0 │     0.07 │    17693.52 │
└──────┴─────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f6d0cc9059a849ff2c6bfc8e27a16993)**

---

## EDIT

Just for pure fun I rewrote it using windowed functions:

```
SELECT *,
    FIRST_VALUE(initial_value) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY year) 
    * exp (sum (ln (1+interest)) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY year))
FROM temp;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2 - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=646985a7742a148671c30f4a9f881861)**

Comment: This is great! I couldn't figure out how the windowed approach works though.

Comment: @pallupz `exp (sum (ln (1+interest)) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY year))` is equivalent of  PRODUCT function(mutlitplication)

Comment: The windowed version really is amazing for my use-case!