# PL/SQL: Calculating compounding values without going row-by-row

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to do a "compounding" calculation in Postgresql PL/SQL and was wondering if it can be done without having to go row-by-row for obvious performance reasons.

In the below table, last column is what I need to calculate. First value should always be 1000 and thereafter it should be previous value multiplied by 1 + Index

| RowNum | Date | Some Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/31/1999 | 0.004624179 | 1000.000 |
| 2 | 1/3/2000 | -0.004028845 | 995.971 |
| 3 | 1/4/2000 | -0.035415729 | 960.698 |
| 4 | 1/5/2000 | -0.005328044 | 955.579 |
| 5 | 1/6/2000 | -0.004885283 | 950.911 |
| 6 | 1/7/2000 | 0.024091572 | 973.820 |
| 7 | 1/10/2000 | 0.015224309 | 988.646 |

Comment: Found a useful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545552/how-to-calculate-compound-interest-with-varying-interest-rates-in-sqlite

Comment: Which column determines the order?

Comment: Date column for order. In this particular example data I haven't added column to partition by.

Comment: Hm. You'd need a recursive query, but procedural code (PL/pgSQL) would make the exercise easier.

Comment: Yes - the answer in my first comment does exactly that. It also has a solution using only window functions.